# Is it permissible in Islam to have sexual intercourse while the wife is pregnant?

Tags: sex, husband-wife, pregnancy

Is it permissible in Islam to have sexual intercourse while the wife is pregnant? If it is permissible during pregnancy, up to what point is it allowed?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be halal?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it permissible in Islam to have sexual intercourse while the wife is pregnant?

Yes, it is absolutely permissible. Islamweb writes on Fatwa no [84328](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84328):

> In brief, a husband can have sex with his pregnant wife. But, if any harm may come to her, especially in the last weeks of her pregnancy as advised by doctors, then one should avoid it. Know that Shari'a does not approve any kind of harm.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR
**Yes as long as it doesn't return harm to the embryo/baby or to her.**

> *"Your wives are a place of sowing of seed for you, so come to your place of cultivation however you wish and put forth [righteousness] for yourselves. And fear Allah and know that you will meet Him. And give good tidings to the believers."* [Al-Baqarah [2:223]](https://quran.com/2/223).

So it's permissible to have sexual intercourse whenever you want, unless the there's direct Islamic laws prohibit it.(Like having sexual intercourse during the woman's menstrual cycle) or if it returns harm to the baby or the mother.